# linux file based using grep cmd

Tags: linux, grep

I have a series of files, for example:

```
ABC_DDS_20150212_CD.csv
ABC_DDS_20150210_20150212_CD.csv
ABC_DFG_20150212_20150217_CD.csv
```

I want to apply `grep` command in Linux so I can extract the first 2 files, but not the 3rd file from `ls`.

I tried to following:

```
grep -l "" *20150212* -- exclude *20150212_201502*
```

Comment: In grep, there is no option **--exclude**. To know the options use `grep --help` command

Comment: Why not simply `ls *20150212_CD*`?

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe into `grep -v`:

```
grep -l "" *20150212* | grep -v "20150212_201502"
```

I haven't seen people use `grep -l` like that though. Using `ls` seems like a cleaner solution:

```
ls -l *20150212* | grep -v "20150212_201502"
```

Comment: `ls` is often aliased, meaning its output stream can have extraneous characters or data.  So if you use `ls`, I'd recommend using `/bin/ls` or `'ls'` to ensure aliases aren't used.

Answer (score 1):

As u mentioned first two files of ls command
then we can use head as well , just like below

```
 ls -l *your_search_name* | head -2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract your matches by using the below command

```
grep -l "" *20150212*
```

**output**

```
ABC_DDS_20150210_20150212_CD.csv
ABC_DDS_20150212_CD.csv
ABC_DFG_20150212_20150217_CD.csv
```

and then to get first 2 lines, you can use `head` command

```
grep -l "" *20150212* | head -2
```

**Output**

```
ABC_DDS_20150210_20150212_CD.csv
ABC_DDS_20150212_CD.csv
```